# Apache Spark Dataframe How to turn off partial aggregation when using groupBy?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

In Spark 3.1.1, I did a groupBy without distinct on a DataFrame. I tried to turn off the partial aggregation using

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.aggregate.partialaggregate.skip.enabled", "true")
```

and then ran the query

```
df.groupBy("method").agg(sum("request_body_len"))
```

Spark still ends up doing the partial aggreagtion as shown in the physical plan.

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[method#23], functions=[sum(cast(request_body_len#28 as bigint))], output=[method#23, sum(request_body_len)#142L])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(method#23, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#58]
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[method#23], functions=[partial_sum(cast(request_body_len#28 as bigint))], output=[method#23, sum#146L])
      +- FileScan csv [method#23,request_body_len#28] Batched: false, DataFilters: [], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/mnt/http.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<method:string,request_body_len:int>
```

I tried this after viewing this video on Youtube : https://youtu.be/_Ne27JcLnEc @56:53

Is this feature no longer available in the latest Spark or am I missing something?

Comment: How did you address this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config `spark.sql.aggregate.partialaggregate.skip.enabled` doesn't exist in spark source code.

All the `spark.sql.*` configurations are defined in the SQLConf object (and this one is not there):
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/651904a2ef57d2261ea6e256e4f3cdd26aa1b69d/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala

As far as I checked, this config was not available in previous versions as well.

In the video you shared, in the relevant slide there is a link for a PR that enables skipping partial aggregation but it seems that it wasn't merged.

There was a PR for the spark project that addresses this issue and add this config (maybe this is the same PR that was presented in the video, I don't know) but it was closed:
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/28804

Comment: Thanks for the help, this makes sense now. I've been trying to turn off Catalyst's PredicatePushDown optimization as shown in <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EIzhRKpiM8&t=528s> @8:48. I used
`
spark.conf.set(
"spark.sql.optimizer.excludeRules",
"org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PushDownPredicate"
)
`
This doesn't work. I guess it's because Spark hasn't added the feature for such a configuration. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The correct config property name is `spark.sql.optimizer.excludedRules` (`excluded` instead of `exclude`). You can find it in the SQLConf object (I shared above the link to the code in github)